# Is $f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac{1}{k})^{z}}$ somehow related to Riemann's zeta function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I was looking at this series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac{1}{k})^{z}}
$$
and wondering if it is somehow realted to the Riemann's zeta function
$$
\zeta(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{z}}
$$
Does anyone knoes if there is a relation between $f(z)$ and $\zeta(z)$?
The kind of relation I'm looking for is something like $f(z)=g(z)\zeta(z)$. I'd appreciate some references too.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I was able to derive the following relation between $f(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$. Enjoy!

$$
f(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{s}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \frac{s^{(k)}}{k !} \zeta(s+2 k)
$$
where $s^{(k)}=s(s+1) \cdots(s+k-1)$ is the rising factorial.

Now we can express $\zeta(s+n)$ as
$$
\zeta(s+n)=\zeta(s)\times\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{p^{s+n}-p^{n}}{p^{s+n}-1}
$$
and for this particular case we have
$$
\boxed{
\;\;\;\;
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac{1}{k})^{s}}=\zeta(s)\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{s^{(k)}}{k!}\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{p^{s+2k}-p^{2k}}{p^{s+2k}-1} \right )
\;\;\;\;}
$$
as I expected.

Comment: No, there is no meaningful connection between the two, other than their superficial similarity in both definition and numerical value. If anything, I would search for a connection to the [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) (a generalization of [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation)), as well as trigonometric and hyperbolic functions.

Comment: $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x+\dfrac1x$ are two wholly different geometric shapes. The former is a straight line, the latter a hyperbola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(n+n^{-1})^{-s} = n^{-s} (1+n^{-2})^{-s}= n^{-s} \sum_{k=0}^\infty {-s \choose k} n^{-2k}$$ so that for $\Re(s) > 1$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+n^{-1})^{-s} = 2^{-s}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty {-s \choose k}  (\zeta(s+2k)-1)$$

The RHS extends meromorphically to $\Bbb{C}$ with simple poles at negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

For large $k$,
$(k+1/k)^z
=k^z(1+1/k^2)^z
\approx k^z(1+z/k^2)
= k^z+zk^{z-2}
$
so,
for $k^2 > z$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{k^z}-\frac1{(k+1/k)^z}
&\approx \frac1{k^z}-\frac1{k^z+zk^{z-2}}\\
&=\frac{(k^z+zk^{z-2})-k^z}{k^z(k^z+zk^{z-2})}\\
&=\frac{zk^{z-2}}{k^{2z}(1+zk^{-2})}\\
&\approx\frac{z}{k^{z+2}}(1-zk^{-2}+O(zk^{-4}))\\
&\approx \frac{z}{k^{z+2}}-\frac{z^2}{k^{z+4}}\\
\end{array}
$

This sort of indicates that
it might be true that
$f(z)
\sim \zeta(z)-z\zeta(z+2)+z^2\zeta(z+4)
$
and that there is an expansion
(maybe)
that continues this.

As to how accurate this is,
I have no idea.